# SQLAlchemy chaining association proxy for great grandchildren?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a four classes like so: `Group`, `Parent`, `Child`, `Toy`.

- `Group` has a `parents` relationship pointing to `Parent`
- `Parent` has a `children` relationship pointing to `Child`
- `Child` has a `toys` relationship pointing to `Toy`

`Parent` has a `toys` `association_proxy` that produces all the `Toy`s that the `Parent`'s children have.

I want to be able to get all the Toys in a Group. I tried to create an `association_proxy` on `Group` that links to `Parent`'s `toys`, but it produces this:

```
[[<Toy 1>, <Toy 2>], [], [], []]
```

when I want this:

```
[<Toy 1>, <Toy 2>]
```

If the `Parent`'s `children` don't have any `Toy`s, then the `toys` association proxy is `[]`. However, the second association proxy doesn't know to exclude the empty lists. Also, the lists should be collapsed. Is there anyway to get this to work?

```
class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=utils.get_now_datetime)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80, convert_unicode=True))
    # relationships
    parents = db.relationship('Parent', backref='group')
    toys = association_proxy('parents', 'toys')

class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=utils.get_now_datetime)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(80, convert_unicode=True))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(80, convert_unicode=True))
    children = db.relationship('Child', backref='parent', cascade='all, delete')
    toys = association_proxy('children', 'toys')

class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=utils.get_now_datetime)

class Toy(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('child.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=utils.get_now_datetime)
    child = db.relationship('Child', backref=db.backref("toys",cascade="all, delete-orphan", order_by="desc(Toy.id)"))
```

Comment: Is this navigation from (grand-)grand-parent only for viewing or also for modifying the underlying collections?

Comment: OK, in such case how exactly do you envision adding toys to the `Group`? if you do `my_group.toys.append(my_new_toy)`, to which `Parent` and `Child` will it be assigned?

Comment: Also, is it true that Group2Parent is one-to-many relationship, and so is Parent2Child, and Child2Toys?

Comment: @PatrickYan Can you add the relevant class with the `association_proxy` code?

Comment: @van - No adding since the parent would be ambiguous. Yes, they are one-to-many.

Comment: But where is your `Child` table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that those are for retrieval and view only (as you mentioned in the comment, adding would be ambiguous), I would rather do a `viewonly` relationship *without* an `association_proxy`:

```
class Group(db.Model):
    # ...
    toys = relationship('Toy',
        secondary="join(Group, Parent, Group.id == Parent.group_id).join(Child, Parent.id == Child.parent_id)",
        primaryjoin="and_(Group.id == Parent.group_id, Parent.id == Child.parent_id)",
        secondaryjoin="Child.id == Toy.child_id",
        viewonly=True,
    )
```

*Note that this is a new feature of SQLAlchemy and is describe in the [`Composite “Secondary” Joins`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#composite-secondary-joins) section of the documentation.*

Then you can use it just for query:

```
group_id = 123
group = session.query(Group).get(group_id)
print(group.toys)
```

Or you can even use it to filter, so to find a group which contains a toy with name "Super Mario" you can do:

```
group = session.query(Group).filter(Group.toys.any(Toy.name == "Super Mario"))
```

---

But in reality all this you can do with simple query, or create a query-enabled property. See [Customizing Column Properties](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#customizing-column-properties) section of the documentation, where you can use any of the simple property, `column_property` or `hybrid attribute`.

Comment: Cool, haven't seen anything about these composite join relationships! I will try that. Yeah, I've been different queries with several joins, but it adds extra lines that I'd like to get rid of. Plus filtering makes this even better!